# Apply a CSS hover effect to an element that’s not a child of the hovered element

Tags: html, css, hover

The tilde sign(~) only works on `#header`. But if I want to try it on
li tag it's not working because it's inside of `#header`.

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
/*
    header:hover ~ .element {
     background-color:blue;
    }
    */

li:hover ~ .element {
  background-color: blue;
}
.element {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <li><a href="#">Hover</a>
  </li>
</header>

<div class="element">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple, without javascript, you can't.

Comment: You can't. But do really need this selector? Are there multiple element elements?

Comment: but javascript goes to lengthy in this case.

Comment: you can if you change to #header:hover ~ .element {} I see no logic on using the li:hover because the .element will be placed after all of them anyways.

Comment: Mr Wumm, I'm only need for concept. because I've to facing difficulties in jquery code for my Tabs navigation menu. like http://www.businessinsider.com/

Comment: I'm not expert or much knowlede in jquery code, but me facing problem on mouse leave.

Comment: Dear  RafaelTSCS did u see demo. is i possible? please tell me if it is?

Comment: take I look at the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```css
#header {
      background-color: red;
    }
    /*
    header:hover ~ .element {
    background-color:blue;
    }
    */

    #header:hover ~ .element {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .element {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<header id="header">
      <li><a href="#">Hover</a>
      </li>
    </header>

    <div class="element">
      <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
```

You have all your li elements inside the #header. So, the div with class="element" will always be placed after the header. There is no need to select the li:hover

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to complete with CSS only, assuming CSS has no methods to go up the elements tree. So you can't go back from child element to parent and then to parent's sibling.
It is possible to make with javascript/jQuery being involved.

Here is some quick and tiny [example](http://jsfiddle.net/25pezgzo/1/) of how this can be using jQuery.

**JS**:

```
$( '#nav a' ).on( 'mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
     var that = $(this);
     var target = '#' + that.data('target');
     that.toggleClass('active');
     $('#sectionTeaser').toggle().find(target).toggle();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="nav">
         <li><a href="#" data-target="techSection">Tech</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-target="financeSection">Finance</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-target="politicsSection">Politics</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" data-target="strategySection">Strategy</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sectionTeaser">
         <div id="techSection" class="s-teaser">Tech</div>
         <div id="financeSection" class="s-teaser">Finance</div>
         <div id="politicsSection" class="s-teaser">Politics</div>
         <div id="strategySection" class="s-teaser">Strategy</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim. Suspendisse id velit vitae ligula volutpat condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Nulla libero. Vivamus pharetra posuere sapien. Nam consectetuer. Sed aliquam, nunc eget euismod ullamcorper, lectus nunc ullamcorper orci, fermentum bibendum enim nibh eget ipsum. Donec porttitor ligula eu dolor. Maecenas vitae nulla consequat libero cursus venenatis. Nam magna enim, accumsan eu, blandit sed, blandit a, eros.</p>
     <p>Quisque facilisis erat a dui. Nam malesuada ornare dolor. Cras gravida, diam sit amet rhoncus ornare, erat elit consectetuer erat, id egestas pede nibh eget odio. Proin tincidunt, velit vel porta elementum, magna diam molestie sapien, non aliquet massa pede eu diam.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS** (just for the sake of example, as you definitely need some other styling):

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font:12px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#header {
    position:relative;
    height:40px;
}
#nav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none; 
    font:12px/40px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #666;
    width:25%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav a {
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}
#nav a.active {
    background:#999;
    color:#333;
}
#sectionTeaser {
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    top:42px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
#sectionTeaser .s-teaser {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    height:150px;
    font:18px/150px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercese;
}
```

So, the idea is to use list of links and separated blocks with content which are connected by `data`-attribute. Once we hover a link, js (jQuery) finds the corresponding block and reveals it.

Comment: But how can I apply it much menu. like this website menu  [ businessinsider.com]. I'm trying to make a menues like it, but I'm failing to do it.

Comment: is anyone to gave me a concept of how to do it?

Comment: Dear CmajSmith. your code looking good. I'll check it deeply and i think it will be very powerful for me if i understand it. thanx Dear

Comment: mr cmajSmith how to handle this. if i use to submenu of any menu which open in dropdown? because dropdown menu goes off according to condition

Answer (score 0):

With this code it works as expected:

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}

#header:hover ~ .element {
  background-color: blue;
}
.element {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <li><a href="#">Hover</a>
  </li>
</header>

  <div class="element">
      <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not use runnable snippets? They are much cooler (and faster) than jsfiddle. Just click copy to answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use javascript if you dont want to change your HTML structure. http://jsfiddle.net/mwno6869/7/

```
$("#header li").mouseenter(function() {
    $('.element').css("background", "blue");
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $('.element').css("background", "green");
});
```